# Placement option in org mode for tables and figures does not work

Tags: org-mode

```
#+attr_latex: placement=[!htpb]
#+CAPTION: Some caption
[[../some-image.pdf]]
```

exports as:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{../some-image.pdf}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
```

So I end up having to do:

```
#+latex:\begin{table}[!htpb]
[[../some-image.pdf]]
#+latex:\caption{Some caption}
#+latex:\end{table}
```

Which is kind of silly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#+ATTR_LaTeX:` syntax differs among Org-mode versions.
You don't need `=` in org-mode ver 8.
I hope following works.

```
#+CAPTION: Some caption
#+NAME: Some-label-here
#+ATTR_LaTeX: :height 5cm :placement [!htpb]
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 480
file:images/some-image.pdf
```